# Fetch SCT list from x509 certificate

Tags: c++, ssl, winapi, cryptography, tls1.3

[image]

How can I fetch this SCT list from PCCERT_CONTEXT? Is there any straightforward win API?

Comment: Straightforward? Not exactly. Been a while since I used these APIs but I think you'll have to use [`CryptDecodeObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptdecodeobject) (or perhaps `CryptQueryObject`) in combination with `CERT_INFO` and then `CTL_INFO`.

Comment: if you need in text form - can use `CertFindExtension(szOID_CT_CERT_SCTLIST,..)` and than  `CryptFormatObject` for `szOID_CT_CERT_SCTLIST`. if need in binary - probably look for https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/inline-errata/rfc6962.html

Comment: Thanks, @Luke and @RbMm. `CertFindExtension(szOID_CT_CERT_SCTLIST,..)` this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following code snippet, I could able to fetch the SCT list as a string from X509 certificate

```
std::wstring GetSCTString(PCCERT_CONTEXT certInfo)
{
    PCERT_EXTENSION ext;
    ext = CertFindExtension(szOID_CT_CERT_SCTLIST, certInfo->pCertInfo->cExtension, certInfo->pCertInfo->rgExtension);
    if (NULL != ext)
    {
        DWORD strSz(0);
        if (CryptFormatObject(X509_ASN_ENCODING, 0, 0, NULL, szOID_CT_CERT_SCTLIST, ext->Value.pbData, ext->Value.cbData, NULL, &strSz))
        {
            std::wstring Buff;
            Buff.resize((strSz / sizeof(wchar_t)) + 1);
            if (CryptFormatObject(X509_ASN_ENCODING, 0, 0, NULL, szOID_CT_CERT_SCTLIST, ext->Value.pbData, ext->Value.cbData, (void*)Buff.data(), &strSz))
            {
                return Buff;
            }
        }
    }
    return std::wstring();
}
```